# DocuSign Bulk Download Documents

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on the API to mass download DocuSign completed envelopes. As of now, everything is working correctly and I can put in a user's full name and it pull all completed documents in this format:

"Subject of the email"-"envelopeid".pdf

While this works, it's very messy on trying to determine what PDF to look at. I looked around at the documentation but I didn't see where the get envelope portion had a way to make this cleaner. I was curious if there was a recipient field where you could do Subject-Recpient.pdf or Subject-Signer.pdf. This could get messy though when their are multiple recipients/signers. Has anyone else come up with a way to make this process cleaner?

Comment: Why don't you just use dates to help chronologically order your documents?  For instance you can query for a set of envelope completion date/times and then append those to the filenames...

Comment: The scenario that came up that started this process was that one of my colleagues sent out the same document to 300 people to be signed. Each one was a separate document and a lot of them signed it on the same day. So therefore with the subject and date only, a lot of the file names would be the same. Ideally I would have recipient/signer.